# Can't write on a sheet containing charts with JXL

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I'm using JXL to insert data in some cells.
I already made a template containing a pre-defined charts (so when my cells are filled, I'll have a nice charts on my dashboard sheet).

But JXL fails to write on a sheet containing charts (I already verified with a sheet that doesn't contain charts, and it worked)

Just in case, I'm using Java/Groovy. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following API:

1. `mouleWB= workbook.getworkbook(file module) //get workbook of file moudle;`
2. `Writeablewrokbook= Workbook.createWorkbook (you file, moduleWB)`
3. use JXL API to manipulate `Writeablewrokbook`
4. `effctive`